# How to shutdown my Windows RT device progmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Hi guys I want to shutdown my Windows device from within my WINRT application. I have researched this and the only code I found in C# was this.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0")
```

However .Process is not recognisable as it gives me an error of you are missing the assembly reference. Is there another way for me to restart or shutdown my device through C# code in a WINRT application?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer is NO. The whole point of WinRT is to put applications into a sandbox and do not allow any harsh actions by any app. And shutdown is obvioulsy not something an application should be allowed to do.